# Select a value of a html dropdown of a webpage with the help of C# windows application

Tags: c#

Select a value of a html dropdown of a webpage with the help of ***C# windows application*** . I am using **web browser control<** for filling out the text boxes , I got stuck with the dropdown please help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the `selected` attribute on the `option` you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer could you pls elaborate it :-)

Comment: I use the following for text boxes anything similar for dropdownlist ??                                          HtmlElement htmlEmpId = WebBro.Document.GetElementById("MngEmpNum");
htmlEmpId.InnerText = "A431105";

Comment: @N.Sai Harish: It should be quite similar. I would do it in javascript first, then simply translate to C#.

Comment: @N.Sai Harish: I can't tell you, the last time I wrote JS was more than 2 years back, but I know the HtmlDocument class in .NET (used by the WebBrowserControl) is very similar to the HTML DOM.

Comment: hmm ok Thanks for your answers I'll try it out and let you know when it is done !!! Thanks again :-)

Comment: @N.Sai Harish: It should all be very trivial once you get the hang of it :) Good luck.